# Is it possible to construct a type which has either all properties of a given type or none?

Tags: typescript

Consider [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4ChnIB4BcyIArgLYBG0A3DsgJ5GmU1YC+WWCA9iAM5hkMZAF5kACjhQA5kXQAfZACUIPKABMAPAKihpAGmQkQ6iDFAR1APgCUoq5jrBhkmQDo8yAIRjSAGz87bFxcHn5uPwg3P25pV2k3emQAamQARhs6Dg4gA)

```
interface I {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const f = (arg: I | Record<string, undefined>) => {
  if (arg.x) {
    console.log(arg.y + 1)
  }
}
```

The type of `arg.y` is `number | undefined`. How can I change the type of `arg` to tell TypeScript that if one property is present the other is too?

If I replace `undefined` with `never`, TypeScript thinks `arg.x` is always `number` instead.

Comment: [`I | {}`](https://tsplay.dev/NrjA0N)?

Comment: It's strange that this works, because `{}` is allowed to have any properties including `x`. But unfortunately it doesn't work for my real usecase; I do need `arg.x`/`arg.y` to compile on their own (as `number | undefined`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map over its keys and make an "empty" version of `I` like this:

```
const f = (arg: I | { [K in keyof I]?: never }) => {
  if (arg.x !== undefined) {
    console.log(arg.y + 1)
  }
}
```

Do not use `if (arg.x) {` since it fails if `arg.x` is `0` (falsy).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4ChnIB4BcyIArgLYBG0A3DsgJ5GmU1YC+WWCA9iAM5hkMZAF5kACjhQA5kXQAfZACUIPKABMAPAGsI9bsNQAaZCRDqIMUBHUA+AJSjbmOsGGSZAOjzIAhCLEzCysQG0dsXFwefm4AGwhPWO5pD2lPemQAamQARns6Dg4gA)

---

Extract to a utility type if necessary:

```
type AllOrNone<T> = T | { [K in keyof T]?: never };
```

Comment: I tried this, found `const i: I | Record<keyof I, undefined> = {}` didn't compile, and never tried the use side. But for my use-case it's ok to just insert a cast there. I still don't understand why it doesn't compile; `Record<string, X>` doesn't expect _all_ string properties to be set.

Comment: And actually, that gives me the final working answer: `type AllOrNone<T> = T | Partial<Record<keyof T, undefined>>` seems to satisfy all my requirements.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Neat. You could also write that as `{ [K in keyof T]?: undefined }`, and `never` instead of `undefined` also works (if you don't have exactOptionalPropertyTypes enabled).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
type I = {x: number; y: number}

type EitherAllOrNone<T> = T | Record<PropertyKey, undefined>

const a: EitherAllOrNone<I> = { x: 2 }
  //  ^ error, y missing

const b: EitherAllOrNone<I> = {}
  //  ^ ok

const c: EitherAllOrNone<I> = { x: 2, y: 3 }
  //  ^ ok

const d: EitherAllOrNone<I> = { y: 3 }
  //  ^ error, x missing
```

Comment: The initialization works, yes. My issue is that the use doesn't work as desired, as shown in the question.